# My THREE.js Raycaster is not picking up certain objects in the 3D space

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, raycasting

I’m to select line objects in 3D space, but the issue I face is that some line objects are on top of other mesh objects (ie., surface mesh).

The line and point threshold I’m using,
Note: world units are in meter

```
this.raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
this.raycaster.params.Line.threshold = 1 / 1000;
this.raycaster.params.Points.threshold = 1 / 1000;
```

objects in the scenario that are not picking up,
[ScreenShot of the Image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pS1lM.png)
The Line marked in the above image is not picking up.

Any help is much appreciated, please let me know if you need more info.
I’m pretty new to THREE.js and trying to learn.

→ In the selection instance I’m intersecting only the line objects to the raycaster but still, in some specific cases lines are not picked up by the raycaster

```
var intersects = EngineService.Instance.raycaster.intersectObjects(nodes1, true);
```

where nodes1 are line objects.